# Why isn't this div floating properly?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have two listboxes and two buttons.  Each listbox is in its own div and the two buttons are in their own div.  One listbox should  be on the left and the two buttons should be to the right of that with the other listbox to the right of the buttons.  This is the markup I am using, but it is putting the 2nd listbox below the Remove button.

```
<p>Available Colors</p>
    <div style="float:left; margin:5px;">
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstAvailableColors" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnRemove" runat="server" Text="Remove" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin:5px;">
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstSelectedColors" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should show the final markup, which is what the browser sees, instead of the code you're using to generate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably float them all left to get the layout you described. `div`s are by default rendered with block-display, which will put a linebreak between #2 and #3, if you don't float them.

Comment: I thought once you do a float on a block-level element, other elements automatically float next to it unless you do a clear.  Is this correct or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Well, the second div does get put next to it, as you said. But then, because it's not floated and is a block, it gets a line-break put between it and the third div, which causes it to go below. Using Firefox's Web Developer addon and turning on outlines for block-level elements can help you to understand this sort of thing visually, I find.

Comment: @Xaisoft: The unfloated elements are laid out as they normally would but they "wrap" around the floated element.

Answer (score 1):

Float all three divs to the left.

Also, you must set an explicit width for floated elements.

Comment: The width requirement was laxed in CSS 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

The fisrt div with a listbox will float to the left and the other divs will take up the remaining space on the page which will be to the right of the div that is floated left.

Is it a 3 column layout you need?
If so you need something like this

```
<div style="float:left; width:66%">
    <div style="float:left; width:50%"></div> 
    <div style="float:right; width:50%"></div> 
</div>
<div style="float:right; width:33%"></div>
```